# Duplicate entry: org/apache/commons/collections/ArrayStack.class

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

Getting following error while generatin APK in android studio

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: org/apache/commons/collections/ArrayStack.class
```

Here is my gradle.build file

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24"
//    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.gogetapps.uternity"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 5
        versionName "0.1"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    }

    configurations {
        all*.exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
        all*.exclude group: 'org.apache.commons'
        all*.exclude group: 'org.apache.commons'
    }
}

repositories {
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

dependencies {
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.0.1'
    compile('com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.2') {
        exclude group: 'com.google.guava'
    }
    compile 'dev.dworks.libs:volleyplus:+'
    compile project(':cmediaplayer')
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:percent:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.0.0'
    compile ('com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0') {
        force = true
    }
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.github.jkwiecien:EasyImage:1.2.3'
    compile 'com.mukesh:countrypicker:1.1.3'
    compile 'com.sa90.materialarcmenu:library:1.4.1'
    compile 'se.emilsjolander:stickylistheaders:2.7.0'
    compile 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.2.1'
    compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'
    compile('commons-validator:commons-validator:1.4.1') {
        exclude group: 'commons-logging'
    }
    compile('commons-io:commons-io:2.5') {
        exclude group: 'commons-logging'
    }
    compile('commons-lang:commons-lang:2.2') {
            exclude group: 'commons-logging'
    }
    compile 'com.timehop.stickyheadersrecyclerview:library:0.4.3'
    compile 'com.github.curioustechizen.android-ago:library:1.3.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'net.alhazmy13.MediaPicker:libary:2.1.4'
    compile 'com.baoyz.swipemenulistview:library:1.3.0'
    compile 'com.nononsenseapps:filepicker:2.5.3'
    compile 'com.writingminds:FFmpegAndroid:0.3.2'
    compile 'com.kbeanie:image-chooser-library:1.5.8@aar'
    compile 'me.zhanghai.android.materialprogressbar:library:1.1.7'
    compile 'com.github.deano2390:MaterialShowcaseView:1.1.0'
    compile 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:1.4.0'
    compile 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.1.+'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.1@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }

}
```

This is the link to dependency map.
[Dependency Map](http://pastebin.com/NcZqeTqK)

Comment: Firstly, do you need **all** the google play services?

Comment: No, I just need Google Maps.

Comment: Then use just the maps dependency. `com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.4.0` -- See here. https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#split

Comment: Anyways, you are duplicating Apache Commons Collections and that dependency output has no reference to "apache". Why are you using projects to compile those, and not their respective Maven repositories?

Comment: @cricket_007 I need these google play dependencies.
`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:9.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-nearby:9.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.2.0'`
but I'm still getting the above error.

Comment: I wasn't saying that to fix the error, I was letting you know that you could "shrink" the size of the app significantly, therefore speed up the build process... Anyways, the `compile('commons-io:` line... Why do you have the project downloaded instead of using the [Gradle dependency](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io/2.5)?

Comment: It is gradle dependency, its another way to write it.

Comment: Ah, right, those parenthesis were throwing me off... Okay, then how about `project(':cmediaplayer')`? Are you using the commons collections in there?

Comment: No, I'm not using it in that module either. I've been having this issue before I added that module. One strange thing happening is I'm able to run the app when on Android 6+ when Instant run is enabled, otherwise it throws this error.

Comment: I honestly don't know where the error is happening. All I can say for sure is that the Apache Commons Collections library is being compiled more than once.

Comment: Yes, I also understand this part. Can't understand why it is being duplicated even though it no where in dependencies map.

Comment: Does seem strange that you are compiling it at all when you have `all*.exclude group: 'org.apache.commons'`

Comment: yes, I've already wasted 2 days for it. I've tired everything I know.